# Struggling with For/while Loops in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Big thanks to the community for the help given so far, but I have hit another stumbling block.

I am trying to run a script that will draw a triangle and then repeat it a number of times as instructed by the input value each being bigger than the previous one, i.e if 4 is enter the first has sides 10, the second 20 and so on.

When it is restricted to a set number of values I can achieve it. But when I use a for loop it goes bonkers.

I am hoping the community can put me show me where I have gone wrong as there has to be a more elegant solution than what I have achieved.

```
from turtle import *
levels = int(input("how many triangles do you want? "))
for triangles in range(1, levels + 1):
    if countList == 1:
        goto(0,0)
        forward((levels*10)/2)
        left(120)
        forward(levels*10)
        left(120)
        forward(levels*10)
        left(120)
        forward((levels*10)/2)
     else:            
        forward((levels * 10) / 2)
        left(120)
        forward(levels * 10)
        left(120)
        forward(levels * 10)
        left(120)
        forward((levels * 10) / 2)
        right(60)
        forward(levels * 10)
        right(120)
        forward(levels * 10)
        right(120)
        forward(levels * 10)
        right(120)
        forward(levels * 10)
        right(120)
        forward((levels * 10)/2)
```

so any help would be great.

Comment: "It goes bonkers" helps no one. Describe the behavior in detail.

Comment: Hi, Matthew. How would you describe 'goes bonkers'? Also, where do you define countList? (I'm not familiar with Turtles, is countList specific to that?)

Comment: What is countList? Did you try drawing just one triangle first?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and step through your code. That way you can pinpoint what you are doing and where it all goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I've interpreted your question: *You want a user to input the number of triangles it should draw. The first triangle should have a length of 10, the second a length of 20 e.t.c.*

Looking at your code. The variable **levels** just stores the number of triangles that should be drawn. The variable **triangles** is what changes with each iteration of the loop. The variable **countList** has not been defined anywhere.

The following is how the code changes in order to achieve the desired result:

```
from turtle import *
levels = int(input("how many triangles do you want? "))

for triangles in range(1, levels + 1):
    forward((triangles * 10) / 2)
    left(120)
    forward(triangles * 10)
    left(120)
    forward(triangles * 10)
    left(120)
    forward((triangles * 10) / 2)

Screen().exitonclick()
```

Since **triangles** is what changes at every iteration of the loop, then that is what needs to be used to determine the size of the line that is to be drawn. Also, the **if** statement is unnecessary since what distinguishes the code for the first triangle from the others is the code:

```
goto(0,0)
```

This function call is also unnecessary since the turtle is initialised at point 0,0 and after drawing a complete triangle it'll end up at the same position.

The **Screen().exitonclick()** is just there to ensure the window doesn't close immediately the loops terminates.

With the user inputing 10 this is how the result looks like:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Here's some simple code that I think does something similar to what you want (Python 3.6.5):

```
import turtle
alex = turtle.Turtle()

levels = int(input("How many triangles good sir?: "))

for i in range(1, levels + 1):
    alex.forward(20*i)
    alex.left(120)
    alex.forward(20*i)
    alex.left(120)
    alex.forward(20*i)
    alex.left(120)

turtle.mainloop()
```

For every iteration of the loop, I multiply the distance my turtle moves by `i`. The first triangle will have edges 20 (20*1) units long, the second will have edges 40 (20*2) units long, then 60 (20*3), and so forth.

If I understood your question correctly, you should be able to work off of this example.

Comment: thanks for the help that has put me back on the right path!